# why didn't "\n" add a silent print in Windows?

Tags: perl

According to Simon Cozens' Beginning Perl, \n is supposed to add a silent print in Perl under Windows, which is true in most scripts I found. However, for reasons not known to me, Perl fails to see \n in the following examples. It apparently has something to do with the usage of brackets, but I couldn't find much info to understand the differences.

script1

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#ranges.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

print reverse (1 .. 6), "\n";
```

The output is

```
654321
       <--
c:\Users\Brenden\desktop\begperl
```

So to me \n was read by Perl and led to a new space. Now

script2

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#ranges.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

print reverse (1 .. 6), "\n";
print reverse qw(1 2 3 4 5 6), "\n";
```

The output is

```
654321
      <--  
654321
C:Users\Brenden\Desktop\Begperl>
```

To me, as there are two "\n" arguments, there should be two spaces. I see only one.

script3

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#ranges.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

print reverse (1 .. 6), "\n";
print "\n";
```

The output is

```
654321
      <--
      <--
C:\\Users\Brenden\Desktop\Begperl
```

As two spaces are created, it means Perl does not squeeze two spaces into one. Therefore, to me, it is likely that in script2, the created space between 2 "654321"s is due to the first "\n" while the second "\n" was ignored. If the second "\n" is NOT ignored in script 2, the output should be either

```
654321
      <-- 
654321
      <--
C:\\Users\Brenden\Desktop\Begperl
```

or

```
654321
      <--
      <--
654321
C:\\Users\Brenden\Desktop\Begperl
```

Now,if I add a bracket in the second print.

script4

```
#!usr/bin/perl
#ranges.pl
use warnings;
use strict;

print reverse (1 .. 6), "\n";
print reverse (qw(1 2 3 4 5 6)), "\n";
```

The output shows

```
654321
654321
      <--
C:Users\Brenden\Desktop\Begperl>
```

What happens to the first "\n" in this output?? The only explanation to me is the space is taken up by the next printout, which includes "654321" and a space (whatever the order). But this explanation doesn't sound right. To me, whether it is qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 ) or (qw(1 2 3 4 5 6),"\n") passed to reverse, in script 2,3,4 shouldn't I still see 2 spaces, regardless of whether "\n" is reversed or not?

Comment: Keep in mind your prompt is `"\nC:\\Users\\...> "`

Comment: Undid my changes and added them to my answer instead. A little bit hard to read that way, but it's more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you know these are the same

```
print reverse (1 .. 6), "\n";
print reverse (qw(1 2 3 4 5 6)), "\n";
```

Then you changed one of them.

```
print reverse (1 .. 6), "\n";
print reverse qw(1 2 3 4 5 6), "\n";  <--
```

So why are you surprised they no longer give the same same output as each other?

---

After you remove the parens that identify `reverse`'s arguments, the `"\n"` starts being passed to `reverse`.

The following two lines pass the result of `qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 )` to reverse:

```
print reverse (qw(1 2 3 4 5 6)), "\n";
print(reverse(qw(1 2 3 4 5 6), "\n"));
```

The following two lines pass the result of `qw( 1 2 3 4 5 6 ), "\n"` to reverse:

```
print reverse qw(1 2 3 4 5 6), "\n";
print(reverse(qw(1 2 3 4 5 6), "\n"));
```

---

The OP rewrote his question full with incorrectly annotated snippets. Here's the correct annotated output.

script1 outputs `"654321\n"`:

```
654321           <== "654321\n" newline one
                 <== prompt
C:\>             <== prompt
```

script2 outputs `"654321\n\n654321"`:

```
654321           <== "654321\n" newline one
                 <== "\n"       newline two
654321           <== "654321" + prompt
C:\>             <== prompt
```

script3 outputs `"654321\n\n"`:

```
654321           <== "654321\n" newline one
                 <== "\n"       newline two
                 <== prompt
C:\>             <== prompt
```

First possible expected output from script4, `"654321\n\n654321\n"`:

```
654321           <== "654321\n" newline one
                 <== "\n"       newline two
654321           <== "654321\n" newline three
                 <== prompt
C:\>             <== prompt
```

Second possible expected output from script4, `"654321\n\n\n654321"`:

```
654321           <== "654321\n" newline one
                 <== "\n"       newline two
                 <== "\n"       newline three
654321           <== "654321" + prompt
C:\>             <== prompt
```

script4 outputs `"654321\n654321\n"`:

```
654321           <== "654321\n" newline one
654321           <== "654321\n" newline two
                 <== prompt
C:\>             <== prompt
```

Comment: Don't think I made a mistake, but when I tried what you suggested, the two prints are still perceived differently by Perl. One is followed by a silent space but the other isn't. Did I misunderstand you or make any mistake?

Comment: @BChen This is a matter of precedence: List operators (like `print` and `reverse`) operate on *all* available arguments on the right. You can specify an explicit parameter list by `function(...)`. It doesn't matter if the parens are preceded by a space. The parens of `qw()` don't count: that is just a quoting operator. Ikegami just showed you how the lines you wrote are parsed by perl. In the second example, the reverse makes the `"\n"` the *first* argument to `print`.

Comment: @BChen that's what ikegami is illustrating — that they *are* different, and how they're different.

Comment: I think I understand it a little better now (not 100% clear though). Still, why would the command - print reverse (1 ..6), "\n"; - give two different results? In the first script, a space follows the output 654321, whereas in the second script, another 654321 follows immediately without space.

Comment: Why would you think the part you didn't change caused the change in output? You have it all wrong. `print reverse (1 ..6), "\n";` gives the same result in both scripts. It's `print reverse qw(1 2 3 4 5 6), "\n";` and `print reverse (qw(1 2 3 4 5 6)), "\n";` that give different output. See update. It should be even clearer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ikegami. Last 2 questions (fingers crossed), as illustrated in your answer, why would some prompt get embedded in the same line with other output while other prompt takes a new line by itself? And what did you mean by my prompt is "\n>C:\\users\.."? I always thought it was just "C:\\users\.." no \n. Again, great many thanks. To me personally a great learning experience, although it's a trivial question for other experienced programmers.

Comment: 1. Because sometimes, you did provide a trailing newline as you should, and sometimes you didn't. 2. Yes you can clearly see that's not the case. If you do `print "a";`, the prompt won't be on the same line as the `a`.